# Browser modify centered div while zooming

Tags: html, css, browser

I'm trying to center a circle in another circle using 2 divs. And I noticed that at some zoom levels the width and the height shown in browser are different from what I specified. I have a 50px x 50px div and after zoom sometimes it gets smth like 49.992 x 49.992.

[image]

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #7154d4;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.inner {
  background: #ff00ff;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

div {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Is this something normal or is there a way to not let this happen?
Tested on Chrome and Firefox.
Here is a testing link: https://codepen.io/StefanAlif/pen/RwMwrMj

[image]

Comment: A .008px difference, that's just rounding. Hardly something to worry about since it would not be something a view could actually perceive.

Comment: is the same thing happen with your outer circle as well?

Comment: Also worth mentioning I cannot reproduce in Chrome

Comment: @KuldipKoradia, I noticed just on inner circle

Comment: @Paulie_D I added a small image to see how it looks when is not the exact dimension

Answer (score -2):

Remove `margin-left:auto` and `margin-right:auto` from `.inner` class

and

Add `position:absolute` to `.inner` class

This will work.

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #7154d4;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.inner {
  background: #ff00ff;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

div {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In what way would this solve the OP's problem?

Comment: "position: absolute" keep the inner circle with accurate space around and width also

Comment: @mhamzase tried with absolute also myself before, same result :(

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).